# Unable to copy dataframe in pyspark to csv file in Databricks

Tags: pyspark, databricks

I am working in Pyspark environment in Databricks and have a pyspark data frame which I will call as df.

I need to push this spark dataframe into csv file, I am unable to do so. Though there is no error popping up but the dataframe doesn’t get copied into the csv. Below is the generic code

```html
path = “ “ #CSV File Location
header = “This is the header of the file"
With open(path,”a”) as f:
    f.write(header+”\n”)
    df.write.csv(path=path,format=“csv”,mode=“append”)
    f.close
```

Only the header gets reflected in the file and not the dataframe

Answer (score 1):

You can write your dataframe as csv using this:

```
df.coalesce(1).write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").save("dbfs:/FileStore/df.csv")
```

Coalesce avoids saving it in multiple partitions. You can put in your own path as parameter in `save()`.